# Проблема с выводом текста

Tags: c#, json, unity3d

Ситуация следующая есть `json`.
Файл лежит в `Assets/Json/file.json`, когда нахожусь в `Unity` и запускаю проект, все работает, как жму сборку, все ставится без ошибочно на подключенный телефон, открывается, а текст не выводится.

Может ли быть так, что файлы `json` пакуется и к нему просто нет доступа?
Кто, что посоветует, как тогда сделать чтобы файл, находился в коре проекта и `Unity` не упаковывала его?

Нужно сделать, чтобы он был в корне приложения и был доступен по адресу.

Пытаюсь обращаться так:

```
string DS = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar,
       DIR = Application.dataPath + DS,
       Json = DIR + "Json" + DS,
       FileName = Json + "file.json",
       FileText = "";
if(File.Exists(FileName)) {
    FileText = File.ReadAllText(FileName);
}
Json Jn = new Json(FileTExt);
//.........
```

Все работает, когда в `Unity` стартуем, а вот после компила, не работает.

Comment: а как вы берете ваш файл ? Можете показать код ?

Comment: @Andrey, обновил.

Comment: если я правильно понимаю, то вы можете загрузить этот файл с папки Resources

Comment: @Andrey То есть мне нужно его в папку с ресурсами запихнуть и юзать `Load.Resources`? или он уже там лежит? Не понимаю. Можно подробнее, что сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да. Вам стоит поместить его в папку с ресурсами и уже оттуда забирать

```
object element = Resources.Load("path");
```

так я загружал свой словарь с ресурсов

И дальше уже рассматриваете его как string

Comment: Все получилось...Сделал так `TextAsset jn = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Json/file");` Ну и потом `new Json(jn.ToString())`,